# Joist was blown out when waste stack was installed in 1952

Tags: plumbing, structural

[image]

Above is the joist bay in my bathroom, damaged horribly by the install of the waste stack way in 1952. We’re in here working on the toilet and would like to improve the conditions before closing it back up.

I was thinking about doubling up the joists for a length of ~8ft, then adding a center joist in the middle of the bay and adding small perpendicular spans every foot or so.
Racking my brain to shore this up without blowing up the whole second floor’s floor.

All ideas welcome.

Comment: I don’t understand what is near the sewer pipe and the notched joist. In the first photo, 1) there is a diagonal board that looks like a piece of sloped roof sheathing. Does this rest on the notched joists?  2) There are several vertical studs. Do they transfer any loads to the joist?  3) There is a steel support (about 2” x 2”) Does it transfer any load to the notched joist? What does it support?

Comment: Is the floor failing? It has been there a long time and unless there is a problem I would not worry about it.

Comment: You might do some research on adding a length of angle iron to the damaged joist.  Maybe that steel support and screws are already doing the job (it's hard to tell from the pictures).

Comment: @LeeSam I’m not entirely sure what you’re referencing with #1, but #2 that is an unloaded 2x6 that the builder used to frame out this wall and hide the stack. It has no joists below or above it. It’s just there. #3 is the foot of the wall hung toilet frame we installed.

Comment: @Gil it’s not, but reading online has made me a nervous mess about potential issues.

Comment: @SteveWellens unfortunately those supports are just the feet for the wall hung toilet. But I’m not sure how I can add an angle iron with the way the drain hub is.

Comment: It looks like a waste line cleanout. If this is the case, you may turn it sideways to avoid conflict with the joist. What is the space below the bathroom, can it be lowered below the joist?

Comment: Related: "How to reinforce a joist with plumbing running through it?" https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/218221/how-to-reinforce-a-joist-with-plumbing-running-through-it